# Cannot create default converter when dll is in a different folder

Tags: c#, wpf, typeconverter

I created a `TypeConverter` in assembly A.dll.
My WPF app. works fine when the A.dll file is in the same folder as the app.

When this A.dll file is in another folder (a sub folder), I got the following **error**:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to
>   perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'System.Nullable`1[EKey]'
>   and 'EKeyId'. Consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ClientKey; DataItem='MItem'
>   (HashCode=25260709); target element is 'Selector' (Name='this');
>   target property is 'SelectedKey' (type 'KeyId')

I don't understand where is the problem ?
I have a lot of other dll files in this sub folder that are loaded correctly.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to examine whether your `A.dll` is loaded into `AppDomain`?

Comment: I suppose it is not loaded when it is not in the same folder but I don't know how to check it for sure.

Comment: Try this code to check whether desired assembly is loaded: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.

Comment: BTW, could you post some code please?

Comment: The assembly is loaded.

Comment: About the code, what code would you like to see, the converter, the XAML ? Don't forget it works when the dll file is in the appropriate folder.

Comment: sorry for late answer. So, it works when dll is appropriate folder, that's a bit tricky. The only thing I could suggest is to get more details about errors/exceptions happenning on initializing the converter(not only 'Cannot create default converter'). This could be done for example by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException +=  OnFirstChanceException;` and logging all the exception details. If you do this - please get back to us with the result.

Comment: It seems there is no exception raised for this error.

Comment: ok then, how do you load the assembly from the subfolder?

Comment: It seems that it is because the ClientKey property that is "data binded" in WPF is nullable. I solved the problem by creating a new IValueConverter and using this new converter explicitly in WPF thanks to the "Converter" markup extension.

Comment: So I didn't really understand the problem but was able to solve it. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: oh, sorry I didn't explain. Basically my idea was that that probably the assembly load process from working directory and from subfolder could differ(for instance they could be loaded in different contexts + there could be some security restrictions which in result could give error you've faced). I'd examine these differences by checking assembly's load context, it's Fusion log, etc. That's it, no ideas left so far.